# Difference in Context for Activity and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to integrate some code and one of the lines I have is:

```
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
```

When I have it in an Activity, there is no error. When I put it in my Fragment, I get this error:
Expected:android.content.context
Actual:this (com.xxx.ScanFragment)

This is the CameraPreview method

```
                     public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera,
                     PreviewCallback previewCb,
                     AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb)
```

As I said, no error when this was in the activity file, so I assume the issue is some difference in what "context" is between Activities and Fragments?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import net.sourceforge.zbar.Config;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Image;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.SymbolSet;

/**
 * Created by Jakub on 7/23/2014.
 */
public class Pay extends Fragment {
    private Button scanBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Handler autoFocusHandler;

    TextView scanText;
    Button scanButton;

    ImageScanner scanner;

    private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
    private boolean previewing = true;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        /* Instance barcode scanner */
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        Log.d(Payspot.TAG,"This is the string:" + preview.toString());
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        scanText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scanText);

        scanButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (barcodeScanned) {
                    barcodeScanned = false;
                    scanText.setText("Scanning...");
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                }
            }
        });
    }




    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }
    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (previewing)
                mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
        }
    };

    Camera.PreviewCallback previewCb = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

            Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
            barcode.setData(data);

            int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

            if (result != 0) {
                previewing = false;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();

                SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                    scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
                    barcodeScanned = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you try passing the Activity context from your fragment? using the method getActivity() in your fragment?

Comment: so would I replace this with getActivity()? Or where exactly do I call it? I replaced this with getActivity() and am now getting a nullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity extends Context, but Fragments do not.  This is why you can pass it `this` for a context parameter.  So the error message sees your ScanFragment as a parameter for Context which does not work.  Each Fragment is associated with an Activity's fragment.  You can either use `getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to receive a valid context to use in these situations.

Your new code would be:
`mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);`

Comment: so would I replace this with getActivity()? Or where exactly do I call it? I replaced this with getActivity() and am now getting a nullPointerException

Comment: Hmmmm, you mean getActivity() is returning null? or mPreview is null?

Comment: I added in my code. Looks like "preview" in one of the lines below the getActivity() call is actually null which maybe is an unrelated issue? It wasn't an issue in the Activity class though, and is now in the fragment

Comment: preview.addView(mPreview); Though the error also appears in the debug line before where I try to convert preview.toString (presumably because its null)

Comment: This is unrelated to the original problem.  Generally for Fragments you perform the view operations in onCreateView() with the inflater that's provided.  You inflate the fragment's layout to get a view, and use that view to use findViewById().

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty unfamiliar with fragments and am just learning them. In that case, do I put in all of my oncreate code pertaining to the scanner into oncreateview? or just that line? also, do i have to change the code? sorry for all the questions but thanks so much for help

Comment: Only things involving the views would go in onCreateView().  So everything from `mPreview = ... to scanButton.setOnClickListener(...);`  Use `rootView.findViewById(...)` to manipulate the views.  And then `return rootView`.

Comment: What do you mean to manipulate the views? so basically replace getactivity().findviewbyid with rootView.findviewbyid?

Comment: I did this. No errors now, it's in the fragment! I am using tabs and now when I click my second tab the screen goes blank, but I'll figure this out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In fragment you must call `getActivity()` method to get the context. Because fragment must be associated with an activity and has activity context (activity extends Context).

Comment: so would I replace this with getActivity()? Or where exactly do I call it? I replaced this with getActivity() and am now getting a nullPointerException